# Set VS Code to always open a new window on launch

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to automate some of my workflow using RPA (UiPath). I want to set my VS code so that it will consistently open to the new screen without a folder selected when I launch it, but I can't find how to do this in settings.

[image: The screen I want VS Code to open to every time I launch it.]

^^^ The screen I want to open each time ^^^

Does anyone know how to set this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following two settings into your vscode `settings.json`:

```json
  "workbench.startupEditor": "welcomePageInEmptyWorkbench",
  "window.restoreWindows": "none",
```

^ Alternatively you can set the above settings from settings UI menu too.

This would ensure that you get the welcome page when opening an empty workbench. If in all cases you'd like to show welcome page then set it like so: `"workbench.startupEditor": "welcomePage"`.

#### Important note

If you had opened a folder/workspace from command line in vscode, like say `code ~/dev/myProj`, then that session will always be persisted during restart of vscode. That's just how vscode works. So inorder to make the above settings work, you have to open the folder/file from vscode command palette(`Ctrl+Shift+P`) rather than from command line(or terminal).